# Pokemon Go without compass?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, compass, hardware-requirements, pokemon-go

I'm planning to get a new android smartphone and have eyes on the Moto G4 Plus. I took a look at the [specifications](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g4_plus-8050.php) and noticed that there is no compass sensor. I would like to play Pokemon Go but the [hardware requirements](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices) says it needs a GPS.

**Edit:** There's a website that says a camera, compass and a gyro is necessary for AR (augmented reality). That means i'm able to play, right?

Comment: According to reviews on Amazon, the Moto G 4th Gen and Moto G4 Plus work very well with Pokemon Go, including AR. BTW, GPS and Compass are two different things, the Moto G 4 has GPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue- but do not worry! Your device can grab your location using your mobile data/Wi-Fi. Its less accurate than the GPS, but it certainly works.

Comment: Is it impact full on the game or not? Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: @Acrylic It has very, very little effect on the game. You may find your avatar wondering around your approximate location, but never wondering around further than a metre or two.

Comment: It will also make playing the game easier. It is much more difficult to play the game with powerful phone, having the video of environment, turn/rotations, ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, without compass, your experience is incomplete, you needed it for know the way to follow the pokemon, but AR works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I use the HTC Desire 626, which also lacks a magnetic sensor. You can load up Pokémon GO, create a character, and get your starter, but you are unable to load any additional pokémon, any pokéstops, or gyms.