# Does Google Maps require a compass to show the direction you are facing?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, google-maps, compass

On my old phone I used Google Maps a lot. One thing I found useful is the dot that indicated where you were had a little flashlight affect to show you the direction you were facing. Does this only work with phones with compasses? I ask because I'm considering getting the motrola g4 plus which doesn't have a compass.

Example: notice how triangular area points down and to right.
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it requires compass or [magnetometer sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer) to show the direction

Specific to Moto G4 plus, maps will work but you will not be able to see direction as you guessed. See [Alpha Dog Senior Moderator](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G4-Moto-G4-Plus-Moto-G4/Total-confusion-over-Moto-G4-Magnetometer-Compass/m-p/3350515#M1126) remarks on the device forum

> Google maps uses gps, so it will work fine.  The actual direction your phone is facing is the only thing unknown. So if you are standing still it can't tell what direction you are facing.
>
> Google maps has been on phones since before a compass was a sensor.

Also see [Pokemon Go without compass?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/151182/131553)

Comment: Darn. Any suggestion of a similar phone that has the compass?

Comment: That would need you to search other sites like  gsmarena, since you know you can't ask for suggestions or recommendations here

Comment: That's fine....

Comment: Moto X Play is similar , but has a compass, and in the same price range- I am happy with it